# Where in eslint.config.js should I specify "env"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, eslint, eslint-flat-config

ESLint introduced a new configuration system in 2022, named ["flat config"](https://eslint.org/blog/2022/08/new-config-system-part-1/#the-path-forward).

[Documentation for the *new* "flat config"](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files-new). |
[Documentation for the *old* configuration system](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files).

As you can see in the ["flat config" documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files-new), the `eslint.config.js` file does not have an "`env`" key/property where you can specify the environment for the linter ("`node`" or "`browser`").
This is easy in the "old" configuration system (using `.eslintrc.js` or `.eslintrc.json`).

Without specifying the `env` property as `node`, I would have to manually add all the node global variables as follows.

*`eslint.config.js`* :

```js
module.exports [
    {
        files: ["**/*.js"],
        languageOptions: {
            globals: {
                console: "writable",
                __dirname: "readable",
                __filename: "readable",
                process: "readable",
                < … more global variables here … >
            }
        },
        rules: {
            // your rules here
        }
    }
]
```

Surely I am missing something?

Comment: Also remember that if the new ESLint docs don't cover this, you should file an issue requesting that the docs be updated.

Comment: For anyone who has a similar problem, refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77499851/how-to-use-new-eslint-configuration-file-syntax-with-extensions-and-typescript

Answer (score 2):

Their blog of all places has more details on "env". This took a *lot* of time to find....

https://eslint.org/blog/2022/08/new-config-system-part-2/#reimagined-language-options

> In flat config, we moved all keys related to JavaScript evaluation [including env] into a new top-level key called languageOptions.

https://eslint.org/blog/2022/08/new-config-system-part-2/#goodbye-environments%2C-hello-globals

> It doesn’t make sense for ESLint to do this in the core, so we are handing this responsibility back to you.
> [ Yes, it does, painfully obvious as this stack overflow ticket makes it ]

Then they show a *rough* example:

```
export default [
    {
        files: ["**/*.js"],
        languageOptions: {
            globals: {
                ...globals.browser,
                myCustomGlobal: "readonly"
            }
        }
    }
];
```

I *imagine* we just need:

```
    {
        files: ["**/*.js"],
        languageOptions: {
            globals: {
                ...globals.node
            }
       }
    }
```

And this works for me (I also added `parser: babelParser` inside `languageOptions`

ESLint is jquerying things up if you ask me, not providing a clear migration path and preplanning their own demise if they launch ESLint 9.0 without eslintrc support and a "not-my-problem" approach to documenting how to migrate from `"env": { "node": true }`. They didn't even document the plugins formatting which is "key-value" mapping strings to plugin objects. e.g. `{ "html": yourHtmlPluginImport }`

Comment: FYI, estlint.config.js is just unusable at this stage as of this date. No major providers (vue/jest/github) support the new format so you can no longer use their linting rules. This makes things a non-starter for our org.

Comment: You've written a decent answer except for the last paragraph.
Why the negativity?
If you don't like ESLint, what's your interest in it?
Why not use [something else](https://www.sitepoint.com/comparison-javascript-linting-tools)?
Why complain about a free and open-source utility instead of contributing?
[ESLint is an open source JavaScript linting utility originally created by Nicholas C. Zakas in June 2013](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/about).

Answer (score 2):

This is explained in the [migration guide](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/migration-guide#configuring-language-options) (highlights by me):

> In eslintrc files, you configure various language options across the env, globals and parserOptions properties. Groups of global variables for specific runtimes (e.g. document and window for browser JavaScript; process and require for Node.js) are configured with the env property.

> In flat config files, the globals, and parserOptions are consolidated under the languageOptions key; **the env property doesn’t exist. Groups of global variables for specific runtimes are imported from the globals npm package and included in the globals property**. You can use the spread operator (...) to import multiple globals at once.

They link to the [globals npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/globals). Then simply do:

```js
import globals from "globals";

const customGlobals = {
  TomSelect: "readable",
}

export default [{
  languageOptions: {
      globals: {
        ...customGlobals,
        ...globals.browser,
        ...globals.jquery,
        ...globals.node,
      },
    }
  }
}];
```