# How to use new ESLint Configuration File syntax with extensions and TypeScript

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

Been looking everywhere for an example of this but have not found one and have not had success setting it up myself. I am trying to leverage the new [ESLint Configuration File](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files-new) format for my React TypeScript project and am looking to convert the following `eslintrc.mjs` file contents into the new config syntax structure.

```js
module.exports = {
  extends: ["@ui"],
  settings: {
    "import/resolver": {
      typescript: {
        project: ["tsconfig.json"],
      },
    },
  },
  parserOptions: {
    sourceType: "module",
    project: ["./tsconfig.json"],
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
  },
  rules: {
    "jest/no-deprecated-functions": "off"
  }
};
```

As you can see, this current config extends an existing config that I have in my `package.json` called `@ui/eslint-config` and sets some things up related to TypeScript. I also need this to be able to lint JSX/TSX files. Hoping someone can help with this...

Comment: A couple quick tips :)

You can use `project: true` now with typescript-eslint: https://typescript-eslint.io/blog/parser-options-project-true. And typescript-eslint's a few weeks away from fully supporting flat configs: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/7694.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to note is that the eslint.config.js file should be at the root level of your project; you can target specific files and folders within the project structure from this one central configuration if need be i.e. in a monorepo.

The "extends" property does not exist under the new ESLint flat configuration schema, as per the 'Configuration Objects' specified in their documentation. You can directly import a configuration and declare it within the new eslint.config.js, *however* if that configuration extends other configurations this won't work - I can't see your '@ui' configuration definition so I have assumed in my code block that it does not extend configurations within itself (if it does, see blog link below on using @eslint/eslintrc 'compat' to bring in such configurations).

The "parserOptions" is also not a top-level property under the new schema and falls inside the 'languageOptions' property.

```js
    // eslint.config.js at the project root
    import ParserTypescriptEslint from '@typescript-eslint/parser'
    import PluginImport from 'eslint-plugin-import';
    import PluginJest from 'eslint-plugin-jest';
    import UIConfig from 'ui-config-path';
    import globals from 'globals';
    
    export default [
      UIConfig,
      {
        files: [ "// Specify the files you wish to target with this configuration" ],
        languageOptions: {
          ecmaVersion: 2021,
          sourceType: 'module',
          globals: {
            ...globals.browser,
            ...globals.es2021,
          },
          parser: ParserTypescriptEslint,
          parserOptions: {
            project: ["./tsconfig.json"],
            tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
          },
        },
        plugins: {
          import: PluginImport,
          jest: PluginJest
        },
        rules: {
          "jest/no-deprecated-functions": "off"
        },
        settings: {
          "import/resolver": {
            ...PluginImport.configs.typescript.settings['import/resolver'],
            typescript: {
              project: ["tsconfig.json"],
            },
          },
        },
        
      }
    ]
```

If you have multiple sub-configurations that you wish to use for different folders/systems - React, Express, Jest, etc - then you can write those configurations following the new schema and spread them into the main eslint.config.js file. This is a snippet of my main eslint.config.js that uses several different sub-configurations.

```js
    import { EslintConfig, ConfigPrettier } from '@packages/eslint-config';
    import { EslintConfigReact } from '@packages/eslint-config-react';
    import { EslintConfigReactTest } from '@packages/eslint-config-react-test';
    import { EslintConfigExpress } from '@packages/eslint-config-express';
    
    export default [
      ConfigPrettier,
      {
        ignores: ['**/node_modules', '**/dist', '**/build', '**/__snapshots__', '**/mocks', '**/coverage'],
      },
      {
        // Client - React
        files: [
          'apps/*/frontend/**/*.ts',
          'apps/*/frontend/**/*.tsx',
          'apps/*/frontend/**/*.jsx',
          'apps/*/frontend/**/*.js',
        ],
        languageOptions: { ...EslintConfig.languageOptions, ...EslintConfigReact.languageOptions },
        plugins: { ...EslintConfig.plugins, ...EslintConfigReact.plugins },
        rules: { ...EslintConfig.rules, ...EslintConfigReact.rules },
        settings: { ...EslintConfig.settings, ...EslintConfigReact.settings },
      }
    ];
```

The following blog post was useful to me in setting up the new ESLint flat configuration in a monorepo structure: [migration-eslint-to-flat-config](https://www.raulmelo.me/en/blog/migration-eslint-to-flat-config)